# jQuerytools Overlay with mask

Tags: jquery, overlay, lightbox, jquery-tools

I can't get the overlay to show up nicely on my site, all I want is a simple lightbox with an iframe that pulls the href from the link its clicked on and displays it on top of an overlay. I have jQueryTools setup on my site so I thought I could use their overlay functionality. Here is my code:

```
 $(function(){
    $("body").append('<div class="oiOverlay" id="overlay"><div class="oiContentWrap"></div></div>');
    $("a[rel]").overlay({
        mask: '#000',
        closeOnClick: false,
        onBeforeLoad: function() {
            // grab wrapper element inside content
            var wrap = this.getOverlay().find(".oiContentWrap");
            // load the page specified in the trigger
            wrap.load(this.getTrigger().attr("href"));
        }
    });
});
```

CSS

```
#overlay { display: none; width:625px; z-index: 1000; min-height:200px; border:1px solid #000; }
```

HTML

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" rel="overlay">Google overlay</a>
```

What I am getting is a box that's aligned to the left instead of the center and no background/mask/overlay effect behind it. I can't figure out what I've missed, this is the page I followed when writing my code: http://jquerytools.org/demos/overlay/styling.html

UPDATE: I gave up on JQuerytools overlay and created my own

Comment: Don't know why you went with that enhancer. [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/) works 100x better.  See [Modal Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal). Oh and your css there indicates that an element with the ID "overlay" is to be hidden with specific dimensions. You might wanna check to see if that element is created on your call and if so, check that its display is not "none"

Comment: Also, you may want to check this [example](http://jquerytools.org/demos/overlay/custom-effect.html) for exactly how to do with [jQueryTools](http://jquerytools.org) what you're trying to do. Altho I still think it'd be easier if you used jQueryUI

Comment: I gave up on jQuerytools and created my own lightbox instead